# XC9536XL CPLD socket

Tags: digital-logic, programmable-logic

I'm planning on using this CPLD: XC9536XL-5VQG44C.
I only have one question when I used the chip in the lab the chip was mounted on top of some type of socket or base and that socket was connect to the JTAG programmer cable. Now my question is if I purchase this chip from [Aliexpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/IC-XC9536XL-5VQG44C-QFP44-Original-authentic-and-new-Free-Shipping-IC/32360437807.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.2.ydhr63&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_9,searchweb201527_3_71_72_73_74_75,searchweb201560_2/)
will it come with the socket or I will need to make one? if not where can I purchase one?

Thank you

Comment: Contact the Aliexpress supplier.  EE.SE is not his volunteer technical support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most likely get the bare chip, so you will need to make whatever carrier board you're referring to.  Sockets for TQFP chips are very large and can be a bit expensive, so it might be a better idea to forgo the socket and simply solder the chip directly to the board.  A carrier board for an XC9500 CPLD should be quite simple, the chips do not require very much support circuitry.

Comment: Probably the chip in the lab was in PLCC package, for which sockets are common. But that would be part number XC9536XL-5PC44.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. I was just going off the part number in the post, and a TQFP socket is not unheard of.